# Call a laravel Route from Vue

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

I got a Laravel Route like this

```
Route::get('/{room:slug}', [RoomController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

I thought it was as simple as

```
:href="route('name.show', room.slug)"
```

Or

```
"{{ route('chat-rooms.show', project.slug) }}"
```

Or

```
methods: {
 projectUrl(project) {
    return "{{ route('chat-rooms.show') }}/" + project.slug;
},
```

```
<a :href=projectUrl(room)></a>
```

Or like any of the 20 other solutions I found on the internet. None Work. I don't get it... Can I pass this from my blade file like maybe

```
<component :test= "{{ route('name.show', NEEDSLUGHERE) }}"> </component>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... checkout this https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Comment: Hey, i used that and it works perfectly. Thanks, it was easy and painless

Comment: great keep this posted it may help other as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is great package by [tighten](https://github.com/tighten)
that you can use

https://github.com/tighten/ziggy